# Not able to scroll the image inside fancybox after Initializing Elevate Zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails-4, fancybox-2

I have a dynamic fancy-box image gallery with Elevate Zoom Implemented in it, When the user clicks on from the fancy-box image the Elevate Zoom plugin is initialized and can see the magnified image in the fancy-box. 
After disabling the Elevate Zoom plugin I'm not able to scroll the image from the fancy-box.
Is there any way to bind the `scroll` feature back to the `fancy-box div` after disabling the Elevated Zoom ? 
I'm using [Fancy-box 2.15v](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) and [Elevate Zoom 3.0.8v](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom)

```
$(".fancybox-thumb").attr("rel","gallery").fancybox({
    scrolling: 'no',
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    type        :'image',
    maxHeight   : '150%',
    maxWidth    : '90%',
    fitToView   : true,
    arrows      : true,
    mouseWheel  : false,
    afterShow   : function(){
      $('.fancybox-image').click(function() {
        $('.fancybox-image').elevateZoom({
          zoomType   : "lens",
          scrollZoom : true,
          lensSize   : 900,
        });
        $('#fancybox-buttons').hover(function() {
          $('.zoomContainer').remove();
          $('.zoomWindowContainer').remove();
          $(".zoomLens").remove();
        });
      });
    },
    beforeClose: function(){
      $(".zoomContainer").remove();
      $('.zoomWindowContainer').remove();
      $(".zoomLens").remove();
    }
  });
```